# wcf service HttpClient encode url with quotes

Tags: c#, http, wcf, url

Necesito enviar un parámetro que incluye el caracter "[" a un servicio WCF.
Aunque primero codifico el parámetro, cuando observo el detalle de la url, la codificación del caracter "[" ha desaparecido. Alguna idea de qué puede ser?

```
string parameter = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("naFwi@dipSoKSws[sdoO");
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("Service.svc/function/{0}", parameter));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres realizar un "escape" de una URI como veo que es tu caso puedes emplear [Uri.EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Ejemplo:

```
string parameter = "naFwi@dipSoKSws[sdoO";
string url = string.Format("Service.svc/function/{0}", parameter);
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(System.Uri.EscapeUriString(url));
```